# Supporting embedded and fullscreen view for custom movie player using AVFoundation

Tags: ios, fullscreen, avplayer

I am trying to create a custom movie player using AVPlayer. I want to support both embedded and fullscreen view. Though I am able to switch between fullscreen and the embedded view, the transition is not very smooth. The AVPlayerLayer resizes itself in jerks. Please suggest how can I create a very smooth user experience.

-Soumya